# How to fill in node names and node values in pic environment with predefined variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I got a graphic with many nodes (~40). I want to add the same type of "sub-nodes" to each of them (view image, one node with a label that contains a name and another node with a label that contains a value). This can be reasonable easily done by combining the `\foreach` and the `pic` or `pics` environment.

[image: Example]

However I did not manage to give the `pic` environment the arguments I wanted to give it. What I wanted to give were the variables I defined e.g. {a-label}{a-label}, {a-value}{3} etc. so that I could update the node labels, I was only able to update the options "e.g. color red".

What is a possible way to do it?

Since the final layout (both in relations and node configuration) isn't clear yet, I'd rather not have many specific written out lines, but a general "function" in which I iterate over with my "node list" that fills in the required "variables" from my predefined values.

Comment: If you define your pic by `pics/nodegroup/.style args={#1/#2}{...}` then you can use it like this `pic{nodegroup={My Lable/3}}`. You can check for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250728).

Comment: It would have been great if you could add a complete example with such a `pic`, perhaps without variables, just hardcoded nodes. Easier for those trying to help if we do not have to start from scratch. Did the comment above help, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to go as @Kpym suggests, another way is to use the fit library to fit the (sub-)nodes into bigger schemes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{bigbox/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=5cm,minimum
height=5cm,align=center},
smallbox/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=4.5cm,align=center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[bigbox,label={[yshift=7mm]below:{"some node A"}}] (A) {};
\node[bigbox,below=of A,label={[yshift=7mm]below:{"some node B"}}] (B) {};
\node[smallbox,right=of A.38] (n-label){n-label: "MyLabel"};
\coordinate[right=2mm of n-label](xr); 
\coordinate[left=2mm of n-label](xl);
\node[smallbox,below=3mm of n-label] (n-value){n-value: [some value]};
\node[draw,thick,fit=(xl|- A.south) (xr|- A.north),inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth] (Fit) {};
\draw[shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,-Triangle,line width=1mm] (A) -- (Fit);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]